# Getting all response headers from jqXHR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On my server (written in Go), I'm sending back a custom header field that I'm trying to read from when I make an ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data, status, request) {
            console.log("Custom field: " + request.getResponseHeader('Custom-Header')); 

            // doing stuff with data
        }
});
```

**The response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Custom-Header: some,comma,separated,stuff,here
Content-Type: text/csv
Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2015 15:42:34 GMT
Content-Length: 1379
```

This will always return `null`. I tried using `getResponseHeader` for regular headers that I've confirmed are in the response packet, such as `Content-Length`, `Date`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`; these all return `null` as well. The only header that works is `Content-Type`.

If I use `getAllResponseHeaders()`, it returns a string with just `Content-Type: text/csv`.

How do I access other headers that are not `Content-Type`? I saw that there was a [bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11624) related to this 3 years ago, but only affected Firefox. I'm using Chrome v 44.0.2403.130 (64-bit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` which implies this is a cross origin request.

From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getallresponseheaders()-method):

> The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing specification filters response headers exposed by getAllResponseHeaders() for cross-origin requests.

You need to explicitly make headers available to cross-origin requests with [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-expose-headers-response-header).

Example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers):

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-My-Custom-Header, X-Another-Custom-Header
```

So:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Custom-Header
```

That said, please use the `X-` prefix for your eXperimental, non-standard headers.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. And thanks for the tip on convention