# ajax GET for custom header not working [CORS, preflight]

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

I'm trying to get a custom header named `X-Total-Pages` when I do a `GET` ajax call. The call is going from a client to an API. 
The API has these headers allowed:

- `Access-Control-Allow-Headers->rigin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,X-Total-Pages`
- `Access-Control-Allow-Methods → POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS`
- `Access-Control-Expose-Headers → X-Total-Pages`
- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *`

The ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: URL,
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  headers: {
    'X-PINGOTHER': 'pingpong',
    "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" : "X-Total-Pages",
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(AuthStore.getUser().token + ":" + ''),
    'Access-Control-Request-Method' : 'GET',
    "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "X-Total-Pages",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "localhost:3000",
  }
})
  .done((data, textStatus, jqXhr) => {
    console.log('waiting patients response: ', data);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(jqXhr);
    console.log(jqXhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log(jqXhr.getResponseHeader('X-Total-Pages'));
  })
  .fail((jqXhr) => {
     ...
  });
```

The result of `console.log(jqXhr.getAllResponseHeaders());` is:

`Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate`

And for `console.log(jqXhr.getResponseHeader('X-Total-Pages'));` is `null`

Can someone tell me what is the right way of getting `X-Total-Pages` please?

Comment: Is `X-Total-Pages` returned within response headers at `Network` tab ?

Comment: Not right now. This is part of the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:accept, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-expose-headers, authorization, content-type, x-pingother`

Comment: It appears the `X-Total-Pages` is not returned within response headers ?

Comment: It does but I can't get the value to use it within my code. I see this `X-Total-Pages:1` How can I get that value then?

Comment: Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924071/getting-all-response-headers-from-jqxhr

Comment: Thanks. If you see the ajax call, it has the header `"Access-Control-Expose-Headers" : "X-Total-Pages"`. That's what the link you put recommends. On the `.success` I try `console.log(jqXhr.getAllResponseHeaders());` and `console.log(jqXhr.getResponseHeader('X-Total-Pages'));` and none of those are working...

Comment: Tried using `XMLHttpRequest()` ?

Answer (score 1):

The browser will send out an OPTIONS request first that checks to see what methods, headers, etc. are allowed.

In the network tab, what does the OPTIONS request that compliments this GET look like? Does it have an X-Total-Pages header?

MDN has good documentation around CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: No. Here's that request: ```OPTIONS /waiting/ HTTP/1.1
Host: api.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-expose-headers, authorization, content-type, x-pingother
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3000/waiting
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6```

Comment: I deleted the `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "localhost:3000",` line and from the call and refresh the page. No more OPTIONS call but I do get `X-Total-Pages` on the response and request: Request `Access-Control-Expose-Headers:X-Total-Pages` and response `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,X-Total-Pages`

Comment: 'X-Total-Pages' on the response, isn't that what you needed?

Comment: You don't need any of the Access-Control-* headers on your GET request

Comment: I need to get it out and do stuff with it. When calling `console.log(jqXhr.getResponseHeader('X-Total-Pages'));` I get null so not sure how to make use of it.

Comment: To be able to access that header you need to see Access-Control-Expose-Header: X-Total-Pages in the response

Comment: Are you sure X-Total-Pages isn't something you send up to the server?

Comment: In this case, I'm trying to read the `X-Total-Pages` not send the value. Most examples online show how to send the info so I guess this case is not that common. I have `Access-Control-Expose-Header: X-Total-Pages` on the header and on the server and still not getting the value on the console. Any idea why?